# Is there a way to hot key skills in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

Im just curious instead of opening up my skills everytime to switch between the options i'd like to do is there a way to like hotkey a set of skills so that you may change your build with out needing to open them back up?

Comment: ... There might be if you have a logitech G13 gaming pad. I'll look into it and get back to you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a faster way to swap skills than the fullscreen menu?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66851/is-there-a-faster-way-to-swap-skills-than-the-fullscreen-menu)

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to hotkey different skill builds.  The closest that came was weapon swap on hotkey functionality, but [that was never implemented](http://diablo.incgamers.com/blog/comments/weapon-switch-hotkey-nah).  Since that was declined, I don't think we are likely to see build swap on hotkey either.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to create an autohotkey-script that could do it? Or maybe something more natively.

Comment: I've had a play with AutoHotkey in the past (though not in a gaming context), and I would imagine you'd still have trouble with the requirement to open the Skills UI as per the question.  AHK could do it ('S' to open UI, appropriate clicks to select skills), but it would require leaving the computer alone while it was doing so.

Comment: What is a autohotkey-script incase i'd be willing to try it, like how would set it up use run download.ect?

Comment: http://www.autohotkey.com/.  It's a macro utility that can replay key presses and clicks when bound to a key combo, i.e. pressing S to open the skills UI and then peforming the mouse movements and clicks necessary to change your skills.  http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm has a tutorial.

Comment: I'd be a bit careful though. Using macros to play the game starts to borderline towards cheating. I am not sure that using such tools would be appreciated by blizzard.