# Can you select primary and secondary skills using a mouse wheel?

Tags: diablo-iii

My play style with the Monk tends to involve switching between a few primary and secondary skills on the two mouse buttons.  The Diablo 3 GUI is not optimized for this sort of quick switching: it requires a few keystrokes or menu selections.

Is there a way to select skills using the mouse wheel?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a faster way to swap skills than the fullscreen menu?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66851/is-there-a-faster-way-to-swap-skills-than-the-fullscreen-menu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to fastswap between the skills. This is intended because it makes you stick with a certain skillset.

Actually it's the community that asked for this because they felt that every character is the same when we get quick access to all the skills. You can not switch the way you want to. You can either go with a build that is all-purpose or have to manually switch everytime you want to use a different skill.

Keep in mind that in inferno you get rewarded for sticking with your skills. It is a buff called [Nephalem Valor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66122/how-does-the-nephalem-valor-buff-work).